# Error when reading a table with blue prism (java mode) with OpenJDK 11

Tags: java, rpa, blueprism, openjdk-11

I get an error message ([image: BPError Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow image]) when I run a ReadTable on a (swing) table in our Java application. I only get this error since we switched from OpenJDK8 to OpenJDK11 (JRE 11).The JAB has been activated and the table is still recognised in the ApplicationModeler via the tree.

Does anyone know this problem with JAVA 11 and BluePrism?

Comment: This is an issue for which I would recommend filing a ticket with Blue Prism's support team, as this is heavily dependent on "black-box" of Blue Prism's Java interaction internals.

Comment: It seems that BluePrism currently cannot support OpenJDK Java11. At least when reading tables

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this type of error in one of my java application.

This was because the java application newer version was not compatible with Blue prism.

Try :

1. Back releasing your java application update. It would be solved then.